# Generar operaciones aleatorias

Tags: c

Saludos tengo que hacer un programa que me genere operaciones aleatorias con números aleatorios, tengo entendido que la función random se utiliza así para que me genere los números pero no se como hacer para que me de +, - * al azar

código

```
#include "stdio.h"  
 #include "stdlib.h"  
 #include "time.h"

 #define OPERACIONES 5

  int main()  
  {    
       int i,numero,numero2;

        char operacion;
     srand(time(NULL));
      for(i=0;i<OPERACIONES;i++)
     {
        numero = rand()%11;
        numero2 = rand()%11;
        operacion = rand()%???????;// Aqui no se que poner
        printf("%d  %d\n",numero,operacion,numero2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar una cadena con las operaciones y escoger un carácter al azar de esa cadena:

```
#include "stdio.h"  
#include "stdlib.h"  
#include "time.h"

#define OPERACIONES 5

int main( ) {
  const char ops[] = "+-*/"; // <-- AQUÍ
  int i,
      numero,
      numero2;
  char operacion;

  srand( time( NULL ) );

  for( i = 0; i < OPERACIONES; ++i ) {
    numero = rand( ) % 11;
    numero2 = rand( ) % 11;
    operacion = ops[rand( ) % sizeof( ops )]; // <-- AQUÍ

    printf( "%d %c %d\n", numero, operacion, numero2 );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar un número aleatorio del 1 al 4 y dentro de un switch aplicar la operación dependido del número generado. Por ejemplo case 1: Sumar, case 2: restar etc...

Comment: Oh disculpa, contesté desde mi telefono y confundi tu respuesta con la pregunta original, enseguida la elimino

Comment: No puedo eliminar mi respuesta desde la app pero mañana sin falta la elimino desde el PC, de momento voté por tu respuesta. Una disculpa nuevamente